# Google SignIn signOut java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet

Tags: java, android, google-signin, google-api-client

It only happens when a new completely new Google user is created during the process.
It works perfectly fine for existing Google user.

My SignInRegisterActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        GoogleSignInOptions.Builder gsoBuilder = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN);
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = gsoBuilder.requestEmail()
                .requestServerAuthCode(BuildConfig.GOOGLE_SIGNIN_WEB_ID)
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE), new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL), new Scope("https://www.googleapis" +
                        ".com/auth/user.birthday.read"))
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                        Logger.i("onConnected");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                        Logger.i("onConnectionSuspended %d", i);
                    }
                })
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
    }
...
    private void logout() {            
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status status) {
                            Logger.i("onResult - %d - %s", status.getStatusCode(), status.getStatusMessage());
                        }
                    });
   }
```

The flow:

1. User clicks Google SignIn button in SignInRegisterActivity
2. User choose to create a new Google account and go through a series of screens (Google account creation process)
3. User sees the permission popup and click "Allow"
4. User is presented with another activity (our Terms and Conditions) - `startActivityForResult`
5. User declines our terms and conditions
6. User is redirected back to SignInRegisterActivity
7. My app is trying to log the user out by calling the above `logout()` function
8. The app crashes with the following stacktrace:

Why? GoogleApiClient should have been connected by step 6. since I called it in SignInRegisterActivity's `onCreate()`.
Was it because GoogleApiClient's disconnect was implicitly called in the activity's `onStop()`?

> E/PRETTY_LOGGER: │ Activity.dispatchActivityResult 
>   (Activity.java:7137) E/PRETTY_LOGGER: │
>   SignInRegisterActivity.onActivityResult 
>   (SignInRegisterActivity.java:239) E/PRETTY_LOGGER:
>   ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
>   E/PRETTY_LOGGER: │  : java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient
>   is not connected yet. E/PRETTY_LOGGER: │  at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaas.zzb(Unknown Source)
>   E/PRETTY_LOGGER: │    at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaav.zzb(Unknown Source)
>   E/PRETTY_LOGGER: │    at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaat.zzb(Unknown Source)
>   E/PRETTY_LOGGER: │    at
>   com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zze.zza(Unknown
>   Source) E/PRETTY_LOGGER: │    at
>   com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzc.signOut(Unknown
>   Source) E/PRETTY_LOGGER: │    at
>   com.sephora.digital.views.activities.SignInRegisterActivity.logout(SignInRegisterActivity.java:253)
>   E/PRETTY_LOGGER: │    at
>   com.sephora.digital.views.activities.SignInRegisterActivity.onActivityResult(SignInRegisterActivity.java:239)
>   E/PRETTY_LOGGER: │    at
>   android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7137)
>   E/PRETTY_LOGGER: │    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4916)
>   E/PRETTY_LOGGER: │    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4963)
>   E/PRETTY_LOGGER: │    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:221)
>   E/PRETTY_LOGGER: │    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1848)
>   E/PRETTY_LOGGER: │    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) E/PRETTY_LOGGER:
>   │     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) E/PRETTY_LOGGER: │   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
>   E/PRETTY_LOGGER: │    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   E/PRETTY_LOGGER: │    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>   E/PRETTY_LOGGER: │    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: on logout check GoogleApiClient .isConnected?

Comment: By why do I have to such check?

Comment: because your stack trace says `GoogleApiClient is not connected yet. `

Comment: Thanks but that's a workaround (I could easily do a try catch) but I want to understand what's going on and do things right